# Ionic 2/3: Passing data to next page by ID

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I'm new to Ionic but essentially I'm looking to pass data from one screen to another, based on the ID.

In my "reference.ts" folder I have the following code..

```
 goToReference1(){
        let id = document.getElementById("1")

      if(id = 1) {
referenceField1: this.referenceList.referenceField1
        this.navCtrl.push(ReferencePage,referenceField1);
      }
      else {
        console.log("nahhh")
      }
    };
```

In my levels.ts folder (the page linking to the data) I have....

```
ionViewDidLoad() {
  this.navParams.get("referenceField1")
  console.log(this.navParams.get("referenceField1"))
}
```

I wasn't sure if there was an easier way to pass and call this data based on the ID. I'm having a hard time displaying it on the next page. I've seen [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T5iGAAypGBA) and it helped a little bit but I'm looking to take it a step further.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You want `this.navCtrl.push(ReferencePage, { referenceField1:"xxxxxxx" });` `referenceField1` is the key for the data you are passing, and then what you are doing in `levels.ts` should work.

[**Refer this too**](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/NavController/)

Answer (score 1):

`reference.ts`

```
this.id = 2;
this.navCtrl.push(LevelPage, {id :this.id});
```

In your next page, in our case `LevelPage` do

`level.ts`

```
this.navParams.get('id');
```

Answer (score 0):

In the sending page import NavController then use this.navCtrl.push(NewPage,{'id':1}); (add navCtrl to your constructor)
in the receiving page import NavParams then use this.navParams.get('id'); (add navParams to your constructor)